# Column isn't in GROUP BY error on join query

Tags: mariadb, join

I'm trying to get best selling products.
Tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE `items`
(
    `id`          bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`        varchar(255)        NOT NULL,
    `price`       double(8, 2)        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `order_items`
(
    `id`                bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item_id`           bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `order_set_menu_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `set_menu_item_id`  bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `name`              varchar(255)        DEFAULT NULL,
    `price`             double(8, 2)        DEFAULT NULL,
    `qty`               int(11)             NOT NULL COMMENT 'item quantity',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `order_items_item_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Following is the query,

```sql
select `i`.`id`,
       `i`.`name`,
       oi.name                as prevName,
       SUM(oi.qty)            as totalQty,
       SUM(oi.price * oi.qty) as total,
       COUNT(oi.order_id)     as sales
from `items` as `i`
         inner join `order_items` as `oi` on `oi`.`id` = `i`.`id`
where `oi`.`order_set_menu_id` is null
  and year(`oi`.`created_at`) = 2023
  and month(`oi`.`created_at`) = 08
group by `oi`.`item_id`
order by `sales` desc
```

The error is

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'the_db.oi.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `i`.`id`, `i`.`name`, oi.name as prevName, SUM(oi.qty) as totalQty, SUM(oi.price * oi.qty) as total, COUNT(oi.order_id) as sales from `items` as `i` inner join `order_items` as `oi` on `oi`.`id` = `i`.`id` where `oi`.`order_set_menu_id` is null and year(`oi`.`created_at`) = 2023 and month(`oi`.`created_at`) = 08 group by `oi`.`item_id`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`name` order by `sales` desc)
```

Can I gen an explanation of why I'm getting the error? This query also works on DB clients (such as tableplus) but not in app (Laravel). How do this can be done?

Comment: Which item do you want the `name` of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 columns in the select clause which are not part of the aggregate functions  `i.id`, `i.name`, `oi.name` nor part of the group by clause.

If you select a non-grouped column or a value computed from a non-grouped column, it is undefined which row the returned value is taken from. This is not permitted if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY [SQL_MODE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) is used , which **I strongly suggest to be enabled**.

You can fix the query by using any aggregate function such as MIN(),MAX(),etc in the  `i.id`, `i.name`, `oi.name` columns or add those columns on the group by clause.

After fixing your data example from an extra comma and two missing columns , the queries are running fine .

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wUuQd7-n)

Comment: Thanks, So how do I get the expected result? I don't need any aggregate on those 3 columns, Just need the data

Comment: @MohammadA.Apu unfortunately I do not know your expected result. Based on your query you need the values to be grouped by  `oi.item_id` and you can apply MIN() or MAX() as I demonstrated on the fiddle . In this case the rows are defined . If you have further question please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) , point 5 and 3 and post another question

Answer (score 1):

Having `name` and `price` redundantly store is a no-no in schema design.  Remove those columns from `order_items` and reference the other table to get those values.  That should clear up the `GROUP BY` issue.

Comment: So every time you raise the price, it would change the price on the previous orders as well?

Comment: Oh -- One is `prie_paid` one is `current_price`.  May I suggest you rename them to make it clear.  Maybe `i.name` needs to be `name_when_purchased`?  Which `i.name` should the `GROUP BY` find and present?

Comment: It's not my question, just caught my attention